# Access of undefined property Keyboard (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to Actionscript 3 and I'm wanting to allow a circle to move down using the down arrow on the keyboard. Here's my code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class Circle extends MovieClip {

    public function Circle() {
        // constructor code
        var speed:int = 3;

        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyIsDown);

        function keyIsDown(event:KeyboardEvent) {
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
                y = y+=speed;
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

When I test it, nothing happens when I press the down key. Anyone know what's wrong with the code?

Comment: `y = y += speed` should be `y += speed` or `y = y + speed`. Also, you should probably make `keyIsDown` a method at the class level instead of a nested function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding KeyBoard events to the stage instead of to the class. Additionally, I would not nest functions like that, bad practice in general. Also the line `y = y+=speed;` is confusing, shouldn't it just be `y += speed;` ?

EDIT: Sorry, I guess stage will be null in the constructor, I've added a ADDED event listener.

Try this:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Circle extends MovieClip {

        public function Circle() {
            // constructor code
            var speed:int = 3;

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAdded);        
        }

        private function onAdded(event:Event) {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyIsDown);
        }

        private function keyIsDown(event:KeyboardEvent) {
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
                 y += speed;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried your edited code. It still doesn't work and I get the error "Line 28 - 1084: Syntax error: expecting right brace before end of program". The weird thing is, there is no line 28...

Comment: I can get it working easily adding it to frame 1 of the timeline. Is this the best way to do it though, or can things get messy?

Comment: Hey, looks like I missed a brace when copying from your question. Just add another right brace at the end of the program and it should work - I'll edit my post to add in the missing brace